# SharePoint list template repackaged, forms now unavailable (“cannot get ghost document”)

Tags: feature, solution-package, list-view, list-form, 2007

I had a SharePoint solution with a number of features packaged inside.  I can't list them here, but it looked something like this:

Features (Scope):

- (Site) MyDocument Content Type
- (Site) Log List Item Content Type
- (Site) Task List Item Content Type
- (Web) MyDocument List Template
- (Web) MyDocument List Instance
- (Web) Log List Template
- (Web) Log List Instance
- (Web) Task List Template
- (Web) Task List Instance

These features have been deployed already, but for business reasons, I had to repackage these items.  In doing so, I combined some of these features, and the new list looks something like this

New Features:

- (Site) Content Types (MyDocument, Log List Item, Task List Item)
- *(Web) MyDocument List Template & Instance
- *(Web) Log List Template & Instance
- *(Web) Task List Template & Instance
- (Web) Custom Lists Rollup Feature

The asterisk (*) indicates a hidden feature.  Now, in order to update my features, I had to retract the old solution and deploy the new one.  In doing so, the list instances became broken because the list templates' owning features were no longer installed.  I changed the feature IDs of the list features in the new solution to match the IDs of the ones in the old solution so the existing list instances would work again.  That seemed to just fine....BUT: the view forms for the list instances no longer work.  When I browse to the URL of the AllItems.aspx form, for example, SharePoint gives me a 404 error.  I've tried to open the file in SharePoint Designer, and get a SOAP error indicating the file no longer exists (although SPD shows it in the tree hierarchy on the left).

As far as I can tell, the only indication from SharePoint regarding what might be wrong is an entry in the log file reading like this:

`Cannot get ghost document: Features\MyDocumentListTemplate\MyDocumentListTemplate\AllItems.aspx`

I'm suspicious of the changed feature IDs, but I really am at a bit of a loss as to what might have happened to make these forms disappear.

Anyone else have an idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3355191 and http://johnnliu.spaces.live.com/blog/cns!90A843AB92E99F!446.entry.

Check all your paths first in your feature to make sure they're correct. After that, I'd try deactivating your feature, making sure in SharePoint designer that there aren't any orphaned files from your feature lying around (deleting them if there are), and then reactivating.

Comment: Hah.  I tried to upvote you, but I don't have enough reputation.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

How about making the broken GHOST file anew.
Using new FORM feature and make a new aspx.

Please see : http://bborole.blogspot.com/2010/08/recover-broken-sharepoint-list-forms.html